# How can I save a OkHttp Client object?

Tags: java, android, okhttp

I am using the current repository as library for my work. I would like to make the application able to save credentials on SharedPreferences, this is, Persistent Memory.

I have tried with ObjectOutputStream but it told me that OkHttp Client is not serializable.

Any clue?

https://github.com/charlieAndroidDev/Instagram4Android/blob/master/app/src/main/java/dev/niekirk/com/instagram4android/Instagram4Android.java

Comment: You definitely don't want to be saving your client to shared presences.... you may want to save credentials you have so you can remake the client when the app loads but not the client itself

Comment: You need to serialize to your object/class/pojo and then using Gson library to can save and retrive you object to Shared preferences. https://github.com/google/gson

Comment: It is a session in Instagram. For that reason, it needs to be saved even when the memory is cleaned. @Quinn

Comment: At the moment, it just saves "user info" and uses it to login and login again. The idea is to modify either library or application to keep the session active ("or check if it is active"). I had previously an object to save only the cookie jar but it was kinda faulty. For that reason, I would like to save the entire object.

Comment: @CrecimientoOrgánico I think fixing your faulty cookie jar would be the better course of action. You can hang onto your auth tokens and keys you may have shared with the server but saving the client object itself is pointless.

Answer (score 2):

Consider an alternative where you do not have to save the entire OkHttpClient:

create a cache model object which keeps all the useful info you use for making requests

```
CacheModel cache = new CacheModel(this.userId, loginResult.getLogged_in_user().getPk(), this.rankToken, this.userId, this.uuid);
```

and then convert this to a string, using Gson https://github.com/google/gson or some other utility, then you can save and retrieve this `cache` object as you need it.

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
String cacheThisValue = gson.toJson(cache);
```

and retrieval

```
CacheModel cache = gson.fromJson(cacheValueAsString, CacheModel.class);
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use [kesho library](https://github.com/alirezat775/kesho) to save anything with timeToLive and encryption.

Document link [here](https://github.com/alirezat775/kesho/wiki)

For using first create a new instance from kesho

```
   val kesho = Kesho(context, Kesho.SHARED_PREFERENCES_MANAGER)
```

Add data to cache

```
   kesho.push(KEY_OBJECT, your_value)
```

Retrieving data from a cache

```
   kesho.pull(KEY_OBJECT, default_value, SampleModel::class)
```